# 'KMeans' object has no attribute 'cluster_centers_'

Tags: python, k-means

I am using Jupyter notebook and I have written the following code:

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs
dataset = make_blobs(n_samples=200, centers = 4,n_features = 2, cluster_std = 1.6, random_state = 50)
points = dataset[0];
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = 4)
kmeans.fit(points)
plt.scatter(dataset[0][:,0],dataset[0][:,1])
clusters = kmeans.cluster_centers_
```

// The line below gives the error: 'KMeans' object has no attribute 'cluster_centers_'

```
clusters = kmeans.cluster_centers_
```

I was expecting it to display the means or the averages of the points.

Answer (score 5):

It's not clear in your example whether your statement comes before or after you call `fit`. The attribute is defined in the `fit` method. Do you call your function before or after `fit` ?

If you do it like this there's an error :

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dataset = make_blobs(n_samples=200, centers = 4,n_features = 2, cluster_std = 1.6, random_state = 50)
points = dataset[0]

from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=4)
clusters = kmeans.cluster_centers_
kmeans.fit(points)

plt.scatter(dataset[0][:,0],dataset[0][:,1])
```

But this way doesn't produce an error

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dataset = make_blobs(n_samples=200, centers = 4,n_features = 2, cluster_std = 1.6, random_state = 50)
points = dataset[0]

from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=4)
kmeans.fit(points)
clusters = kmeans.cluster_centers_

plt.scatter(dataset[0][:,0],dataset[0][:,1])
```